# Missing icons in Gnome System Settings

Tags: 12.04, gnome, icons

I have installed a Ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 server, and Gnome Shell on top of it.
Now I am missing some icons from the Gnome System Settings dialog.

The missing icons is marked with red circles, on [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbmEJ.png).
Mine only shows a small black box with a red stop sign.
Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract this file to /usr/share/icons/your.current.icon.theme/categories/24 then reopen Gnome System Settings.

http://ubuntuone.com/1si6OVYcMVmDe5uJwBDz3L